# Video does not play in Kindle fire. application crashing android

Tags: android, video-streaming, kindle-fire

In my app i m loading some video mp4 files and it plays on tablet and other android devices but when i try to play the same video on kindle fire the application crashes. Any suggestions please. Please look into my code

```
public class VideoPlayer extends Activity {

private VideoView vidPlayer;
private ImageView ivPlayerBG;
private MediaController mc;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.videoplayer);
    Utils.setOrientation(this);
    vidPlayer = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vidPlayer);
    ivPlayerBG = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPlayerBG);
    mc = new MediaController(this);
    vidPlayer.setMediaController(mc);
    vidPlayer.setFocusable(true);
    mc.show(0);
    //onControllerHide();

    AudioManager audioMan = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    if (audioMan.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC) <= 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "volume is set to mute", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    Log.v("totla memory play", "" + Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
    Log.v("HEAP_SIZE ", "" + Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize());

    Boolean isAudio = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("audio");
    if (null != isAudio && isAudio) {
        ivPlayerBG.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }

    Uri videoUrl = Uri.parse(Utils.getSDCardPath(getIntent().getExtras()
            .getString("url"))); // Uri.parse(Utils.getSDCardPath("Media/video.mp4"));
    Log.v("log" + videoUrl.getPath(), "logv");
    playVideo(videoUrl);

}

public void onControllerHide() {
    mc.hide();
}

public void playVideo(Uri videouri) {
    try {
        vidPlayer.setVideoURI(videouri);
        vidPlayer.requestFocus();
        vidPlayer.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Just use this code.

```
 Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
             Uri.parse(url));
      startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindle fire is an amazon specific book reading application. If you want to install any application in it, you need to first [root the device](http://www.pcworld.com/article/244303/how_to_root_your_kindle_fire.html). Try installing apk of Daroon Player (available on their website) and then install your application. It will work.

Comment: my device has been rooted and been installing android apps quiet long back... whre would i get the player

Comment: you will get it in Daroon's website. http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/media_and_video/daroon-player_bdqdv.html

Comment: Also this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.daroonplayer.dsplayer&feature=search_result